# laravel 5 uuid generation code errors

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to use UUid in laravel 5. I have added the following code :

```
$fileUniqueName = Uuid::generate();
```

and at top :

```
use Uuid;
```

But I am getting the following error :

FatalErrorException in FlyersController.php line 427:
Class 'Uuid' not found

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not `use`-ing the correct namespace for the `Uuid` class. You should have at the top of your file something like this for [webpatser's uuid generator](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid):

`use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;`

If you want to use Uuid in Laravel 5, I've put together some simple traits to use in your models. You can find the source code [on github](https://github.com/alsofronie/eloquent-uuid).